# C unix socket programming, connect() hanging on invalid host name

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, freeze

I'm having a hanging issue with the `connect` function when I pass an invalid host name.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ERROR_NUM           -1
#define BUFFER_SIZE         500
#define HOST_NAME_SIZE      255
#define MY_ID       5

int  main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int hSocket;                 /* handle to socket */
struct hostent* pHostInfo;   /* holds info about a machine */
struct sockaddr_in Address;  /* Internet socket address stuct */
long nHostAddress;
char pBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char userName[BUFFER_SIZE];
char hostName[HOST_NAME_SIZE];

if(argc < 2){
    printf("\nUsage: username@hostname\n");
    return 0;
}
else{
    int i = 0;
    int length;
    if((length = strlen(argv[1])) >= BUFFER_SIZE){
        printf("Argument entered is too long\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while(*(argv[1] + i) != '@'){
        ++i;
        if(i >= length){
            printf("Usage: username@hostname\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    strncpy(userName, argv[1], i);
    argv[1]+=(i+1);
    strcpy(hostName,argv[1]);
}

printf("\nMaking a socket\n");
if((hSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)) == ERROR_NUM){
    printf("\nCould not make a socket\n");
    return 0;
}

/* get IP address from name */
pHostInfo=gethostbyname(hostName);
if(!pHostInfo){
    printf("Could not resolve host name\n");
    return 0;
}
/* copy address into long */
memset(&nHostAddress, 0, sizeof(nHostAddress));
memcpy(&nHostAddress,pHostInfo->h_addr,pHostInfo->h_length);

/* fill address struct */
Address.sin_addr.s_addr=nHostAddress;
Address.sin_family=AF_INET;
/* finding host port num */
int x = 5000 + (MY_ID-1)* 10;
int y = 5000 + (MY_ID*10) - 1;
for(x; x <= y; ++x){
    Address.sin_port=htons(x);
    if(connect(hSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&Address,sizeof(Address)) > ERROR_NUM){
        break;
    }
}
if(x > y){
    printf("\nFailed to connect to host port\n");
    return 0;
}
printf("\nConnected to %s on port %d\n", hostName, x);
printf("Client closing socket\n\n");                    
if(close(hSocket) == ERROR_NUM){
    printf("\nCould not close socket\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`connect()` is hanging if I give an invalid host name as an argument.  If I give a valid host name everything works according to plan.  A valid host name but invalid port will go to return 0.

My question is, why is it hanging and not returning -1 when I give an invalid host name?

Comment: Because you're not checking the return value of `gethostbyname`?

Comment: Shouldn't connect still return -1 if the gethostbyname() func doesn't find the address? Which would then assign NULL to pHostInfo.  I'll try that out and see what happens. And i'll run it through gdb to see what gethostbyname() is actually assigning with a bad host name and get back to you shortly.

Comment: no, it will probably try to connect to an address that's uninitialized memory (or maybe `0.0.0.0`, depending on the implementation).  I suspect wireshark will show you packets going out and no responses and if you wait long enough, your connect will eventually timeout.

Comment: You should really use `getaddrinfo`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking the return value from `gethostbyname`. If it fails, your current program exhibits undefined behavior because you're dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Oop, good catch, forgot that `gethostbyname` returned `NULL`.

Comment: Just added the code in the edit above with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: @pandaEater: hard to tell. I can't even compile your code because of the erroneous assignment to `strHostName`.

Comment: @larsmans Sorry about that. Just added some more code to make it compile.